# Unused tables in FROM crashing query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database tables :

```
user
    int unsigned id
    varchar      login

group
    int unsigned id
    varchar      label

right
    int unsigned id
    varchar      label

user_group
    int unsigned userId
    int unsigned groupId

user_right
    int unsigned userId
    int unsigned rightId

group_right
    int unsigned groupId
    int unsigned rightId
```

A right is considered as granted to a group or a user when it's associated using user_right or group_right tables (respectivly).
I have the following query that is supposed to retrieve an user's rights from his login :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `R`.`id`,
                `R`.`label`
FROM `user` `U`,
     `right` `R`,
     `user_right` `UR`,
     `user_group` `UG`,
     `group_right` `GR`
WHERE (`U`.`id` = `UR`.`userId`
       AND `R`.`id` = `UR`.`rightId`
       OR `U`.`id` = `UG`.`userId`
       AND `UG`.`groupId` = `GR`.`groupId`
       AND `R`.`id` = `GR`.`rightId`)
  AND `U`.`login` = 'admin'
```

When a user is associated to rights and groups, the query does work and returns the right rights. But when a user has no group, the query does not work. If i remove the unused tables (user_group and group_rights), it does work again.

What should i add to my query to avoid this ? Should I add something like "OR some_column IS NULL" ? I'd appreciate if you could also explain me why so i don't meet this problem again.

Thanks in advance.

Some sample datas :

```
user (id, login)
1 'admin'

right (id, label)
1 'r1',
2 'r2',
3 'r3'

user_right (id, label)
1 1
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Just saying: `right` and `group` are reserved words.

Comment: Yes, that's why i'm using backquotes. I'll change this later, but i need to solve this before.

Comment: "I'll change this later" -> famous last words.

Comment: The hodgepodge of AND and OR in the WHERE clause is always a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using implicit joins, and, the way you wrote your query, they are `INNER JOIN`s. You should change your query to use proper explicit joins, and use `LEFT JOIN`s in there. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `R`.`id`,
                `R`.`label`
FROM `user` `U`
LEFT JOIN `user_right` `UR`
    ON `U`.`id` = `UR`.`userId`
LEFT JOIN `right` `R`
    ON `R`.`id` = `UR`.`rightId`
LEFT JOIN `user_group` `UG`
    ON `U`.`id` = `UG`.`userId`
LEFT JOIN `group_right` `GR`
    ON `UG`.`groupId` = `GR`.`groupId` AND `R`.`id` = `GR`.`rightId`
WHERE `U`.`login` = 'admin'
```

Comment: Thanks. I've never been using **** JOINs until now. I was only tought to use WHERE joins by doing either like i did or by using nested SELECTs. I should probably have a deeper look at this.
Also i would like to keep cross database compatibility. Aren't LEFT JOINs mysql specific ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`s,`LEFT JOIN`s, `RIGHT JOIN`s, etc) are the ANSI standard, they will work on any RDBMS.